# EF doesnt want to map my class properly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following class Aggregate:

```
public class Aggregate
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }

    public virtual OuterClass Outer { get; set; }
}

public class A:C
{
}

public class B:C
{
}

public class C
{
    public bool Val1 { get; set; }
    public bool Val2 { get; set; }      
}
```

OuterClass has been already added to table, Aggregate class has 1-1 with OuterClass table.

I want to map my Aggregate class to two different tables: A and B like this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Aggregate>().HasRequired(x => x.Outer).WithRequiredDependent();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Aggregate>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.Properties(p => new { p.Id, p.A });
            m.ToTable("A");
        }).Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.Properties(p => new { p.Id, p.B });
            m.ToTable("B");
        });
```

Then i add migration and become following:

```
       CreateTable(
            "A",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 19, scale: 0),
                    A_Val1 = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 1, scale: 0),
                    A_Val2 = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 1, scale: 0),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("OuterTable", t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.Id);         

        CreateTable(
            "B",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 19, scale: 0),
                    B_Val1 = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 1, scale: 0),
                    B_Val2 = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 1, scale: 0),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("A", t => t.Id) /*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
            .Index(t => t.Id);
```

Why the second table wants to add FK to the first one? How to tell EF to add FK "OuterTable" instead?

Comment: That's how EntityFramework works. If you split a single entity to multiple table, one of the table acts as a master table holding all primary info including foreign keys, other tables containing only specific columns and 1-1 relation to master table, in this case table `A`

Comment: is there a way to do what i want?

Comment: No, If I understand correctly, you are trying to create a DbSet<Entity> where it is a union of two or more independent tables, right? Not possible as far as I know,

Comment: correctly. Thanks, ill try to come up smtng else